# How to find the URL path to a local postgres database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a Rails app running on a postgres database. I'm setting up a background task queue running on the database, and I need to specify the database URL.

The various permutations I've tried and would expect all return `FATAL:  database "database-name" does not exist`.

Is there a command that will print this URL?

Or, what should the URL look like if my database.yml looks like this

```
development:
    adapter: postgresql
    encoding: unicode
    database: db/database-name
```

Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: The classic approach is to inspect the postgres logfile, just to see what the frontend attempted.

Comment: And what **is** the name of the database in PostgreSQL?

Comment: John D, but it smells as sweet as a horse by any other name

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The format appears to be

```
postgres://username:password@host/database
```

You have a `/` in your database name and (apparently) postgres will accept `/` in database names, so you need to use either

```
postgres:///db/database-name
```

or

```
postgres:///db%2Fdatabase-name
```

Feel free to take out the `db/` part of your database name - it's only warranted for databases like SQLite that store the db in a local file and need a filename.

Comment: The db path was the problem. I was hoping for a way around this, as I already had data in the database. In the end I dropped, recreated without db in the name, and imported a backup. Works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you're attempting to access the database, but if you are attempting to create a script that uses the same database as rails but is run separately, consider using a script that runs in rails.  In unix/linux, if you add this line:

```
#! script/rails runner
```

to the first line of your script and then make it executable with:

```
chmod +x myscript
```

then you can simply run it with

```
./myscript
```

and it can use your model classes just like your controller and view code in rails.  Then there is no need to access the database manually.

Comment: thanks michael, no i just need the connection path to the database. I'm trying to incorporate queue_classic into my app https://github.com/ryandotsmith/queue_classic.

Comment: the problem I'm facing is my database.yml defines the path `db/database-name` but the error is `FATAL:  database "dbdatabase-name" does not exist` - note no slash separator after the db. So I'm looking for a way to interrogate and work out what path Rails is using. Any ideas?